# Bitnami Magento site always point to port 80 for any links

Tags: magento, mariadb, magento2, bitnami

I am new to this area. I have a docker-compose.yml file which starts Magento & MariaDB dockers container. And here is the script:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:latest'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb'
  magento:
    image: 'bitnami/magento:latest'
    environment:       
      - ENVIRONMENT=Test3
    ports:
      - '89:80' #for Test3              
    volumes:
      - 'magento_data:/bitnami/magento'
      - 'apache_data:/bitnami/apache'
      - 'php_data:/bitnami/php'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  magento_data:
    driver: local
  apache_data:
    driver: local
  php_data:
    driver: local
```

I tried to use http://127.0.0.1:89 for the site, and it did happen at beginning (e.g. I could open site with URL: http://127.0.0.1:89 ). However when I view page source I found these style/js still points to http://127.0.0.1 (port 80) one. Also I couldn't access its other page like http://120.0.0.1:89/admin.

Then I google, for example some posts mention I need to change base_url value in "core_config_data" table which I did (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/how-do-i-fix-my-base-urls-so-i-can-access-my-magento-site). And I do clear the **var/cache** folder on both Magento & MariaDB containers, but result is still the same. (I didn't find **var/session** folder which that link mentions. Maybe a little bit different among Bitnami system and others.)

So how could I try now? And also is there anyway that I could set base_url with correct port to MariaDB at very beginning in my **docker-compose.yml** file?

P.S. Everything works fine if using default port 80.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can indicate the port where Apache should be listening in the `docker-compose.yml` file in this way:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:latest'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb'
  magento:
    image: 'bitnami/magento:latest'
    ports:
      - '89:89'
      - '443:443'
    environment:
      - APACHE_HTTP_PORT=89
    volumes:
      - 'magento_data:/bitnami/magento'
      - 'php_data:/bitnami/php'
      - 'apache_data:/bitnami/apache'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb

volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  magento_data:
    driver: local
  apache_data:
    driver: local
  php_data:
    driver: local
```

Please, note the use of the `APACHE_HTTP_PORT` environment variable on the Magento container. Also, note that the `port` forwarding should be `89:89` in this case.

Take into account that this change should be performed when you launch for the first time the containers. That means that, if you have some volumes already, this method won't work because your configuration will be restored from those volumes. So, ensure that you don't have any volume. You can check it by executing

```
docker volume ls
```

and checking that there isn't any volume named

```
local               DATE_apache_data
local               DATE_magento_data
local               DATE_mariadb_data
```

Also, you can also delete the volumes executing:

```
docker-compose down -v
```

Comment: Hi Jose, it works great! One more question: if you use "docker-compose down -v" will it delete all volumes? usually I use "docker volume rm xxxxxxx" to delete certain volume. Do you know whether I could use wildcast for remove command? (e.g. volume names usually have the same prefix.) Thanks again!

Comment: The command `docker-compose down -v` will only delete the volumes create by the services defined in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

If you want to delete only a single volume or any volume you can use the classic `docker volume rm VOLUME`. Also, since docker 1.13, there is the `docker volume prune` command that removes all dangling volumes you have on your system.

On the other hand, if you want to delete some volumes with a certain pattern in its name you can use something like `docker volume rm $(docker volume ls | egrep PATTERN | awk "{print \$2}")`

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy!